# Google Drive in GNOME - garbled file names in other applications

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 19.04, google-drive

I've used the GNOME method of linking my Google account, so that my files show up in Nautilus under "user@gmail.com". This works fine, as long as I stay in Nautilus. If I view the files in terminal, Filezilla, etc., all the file names are garbled:

[image]

Is there really no way to utilize the fact that I can access my Google Drive files from GNOME in other applications?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. This seems to be a bug, because in Nuatilus indeed eveything is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this issue in lubuntu 20.04 when displaying google drive with pcmanfm-qt file manager.
However, I could solve it by going to 'Edit' - 'Preferences' menu, 'Display' tab and unchecking the 'Always show full file names' check box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lubuntu and had same behave, what I did was unchecking on menu
Edit/Preferences/Display/

The next option:

[image]

After restarting the file manager all was out of the box...